# Scheme (Checking equality for lists, numbers and symbols)

Tags: list, scheme

I'm a relatively new user of scheme and am attempting to make a function that is able to check the equality of numbers, symbols and lists (including nested lists). I've tried multiple variants of the code below and haven't been able to come up with a working solution; the main problems being that after encountering a nested list the program will not continue past that point if there were more elements in the original list, and I am unsure how to make the function work for lists and numbers/symbols. Any help is appreciated.

As a note, I'm in the R5RS language within Scheme, which I understand limits the functions of the language.

```
(define (my-equal? a b)
  (cond ((null? a))
        ((list? (car a))(my-equal? (car a)(car b)))
        ((equal? (car a)(car b))
         (my-equal? (cdr a)(cdr b)))
        (else #f)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `a` satisfies `null?`, you don't return anything explicitely. But what is the correct answer? the equality holds if you have `(null? b)` in that case.

Next, you assume that you can take the `car` of `a` and test *that* value against the `list?` predicate. Actually, you first have to check that `a` itself is a list in order to be allowed to access its first element.

In all your next clauses, you manipulate `car` and `cdr` of your inputs instead of using `a` and `b` directly.
The only case when you need to use them is when you are sure that *both* `a` and `b` are lists: then, they are equal if their `car` are equals and their `cdr` too.

The other cases cannot assume that the values are lists. On the contrary, when `list?` fails in your `cond`, you are sure you are dealing with another kind of input. You cannot call `(car a)` in the following lines without expecting an error.

Then, you have to provide other ways of comparing `a` and `b`, if they both are numbers, or strings, or other types.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether this is a "I just want to implement it myself" type of question, but in the R5RS standard, the documentation for `equal?` states:

Equal? recursively compares the contents of pairs, vectors, and strings, applying eqv? on other objects such as numbers and symbols. A rule of thumb is that objects are generally equal? if they print the same. Equal? may fail to terminate if its arguments are circular data structures.

So... `equal?` already handles recursive checking of nested lists, vectors, etc.

Again, if you're just interested in how one might implement something like this, then don't let me stop you!